# Is there any "standard" way to calculate the numerical gradient?

Tags: c++, math, precision, numerical-methods

I am trying to calculate the numerical gradient of a smooth function in c++. And the parameter value could vary from zero to a very large number(maybe 1e10 to 1e20?)

I used the function f(x,y) = 10*x^3 + y^3 as a testbench, but I found that if x or y is too large, I can't get correct gradient.

Here is my code to calculate the graidient:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
double f(double x, double y)
{
    // black box expensive function
    return 10 * pow(x, 3) + pow(y, 3);
}
int main()
{
    // double x = -5897182590.8347721;
    // double y = 269857217.0017581;
    double x = 1.13041e+19;
    double y = -5.49756e+14;
    const double epsi = 1e-4;

    double f1 = f(x, y);
    double f2 = f(x, y+epsi);
    double f3 = f(x, y-epsi);
    cout << f1 << endl;
    cout << f2 << endl;
    cout << f3 << endl;
    cout << f1 - f2 << endl; // 0
    cout << f2 - f3 << endl; // 0
    return 0;
}
```

If I use the above code to calculate the gradient, the gradient would be zero!

The testbench function, 10*x^3 + y^3, is just a demo, the real problem I need to solve is actually a black box function.

So, is there any "standard" way to calculate the numerical gradient?

Comment: Did you do the math for "_large x and y_" w.r.t. to `x^3` and `y^3`? Hint: `double` has its limits.

Comment: The standard way to calculate gradient is calculus.  How you implement it numerically is your responsibility.   (10^19)^3 = 10^57, right?

Comment: @duffymo that's *well* within the range of a `double` (1e308, ISTR)

Comment: how "incorrect" is the gradient?   With a ∂x as high as 1e-4 and numbers that large, you're bound to get errors.

Comment: Yes, it is.  I'm responding to "double has its limits".  You aren't there yet.

Comment: How incorrect?  You have a closed form expression.  You can calculate the components of the gradient exactly and compare that to the approximations you're calculating using differences.

Comment: you should take care about the fact that epsi should be not absorbed by y else your gradient is 0. So you should not define epsi as const but relatively to y like (DBL_EPSILON * 1000)*y.

Comment: You are asking for a precision of at least 18 decimal digits (since `|y| > 1e14` and `epsi = 1e-4`). That is at least `18/log10(2) ~ 60` bits, and the double-precision format only has 53 bits of significand precision. You need another type.

Comment: What even is the definition of the gradient of a 2D function like that ?

Comment: @Alnitak The gradient of a function is the vector of its partial derivatives. In this case, it's `[df/dx, df/dy] = [30x^2, 3y^2]`.

Comment: @Nelxiost right, so that's what I thought, so it's not even a scalar.

Comment: @Alnitak Well, what the OP is trying to print is the scalar `df/dy` at `y = -5.49756e+14` (with some `epsi` factor in there).

Comment: Although its not really a numerical method you could use automatic differentiation: see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation)

Comment: @Alnitak When I evaluate the above code to calculate gradient, the calculated gradient is **zero**

Answer (score 11):

In the first place, you should use the central difference scheme, which is more accurate (by cancellation of one more term of the Taylor develoment).

```
(f(x + h) - f(x - h)) / 2h
```

rather than

```
(f(x + h) - f(x)) / h
```

Then the choice of `h` is critical and using a fixed constant is the worst thing you can do. Because for small `x`, `h` will be too large so that the approximation formula no more works, and for large `x`, `h` will be too small, resulting in severe truncation error.

A much better choice is to take a relative value, `h = x√ε`, where `ε` is the machine epsilon (1 ulp), which gives a good tradeoff.

```
(f(x(1 + √ε)) - f(x(1 - √ε))) / 2x√ε
```

Beware that when `x = 0`, a relative value cannot work and you need to fall back to a constant. But then, nothing tells you which to use !

Comment: -1: Just because x is large does not mean that you can take a larger h! Evaluating the gradient of `f(x)` at `x=1` is the same problem as evaluating the gradient of `g(x) = f(x-1000)` at `x = 1001` i.e. the same `h` is required.

Comment: @Troubadour: not at all. Following your idea, evaluating at `10^16` with `h=1` would always yield `0`. `h` must be proportional to `x` with a coefficient halfway of the machine epsilon. -1 to you.

Comment: I'm assuming that the `sqrt(epsilon)` is chosen so that the final error is `O(epsilon)`. If so looking deeper at the error term shows that the error actually comes out as O(x^2 epsilon), but we really want it to be O(|x| epsilon), so maybe a better choice for h would be sqrt( |x| epsilon)?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: you also miss the idea. Maybe NR will better convince you http://www.it.uom.gr/teaching/linearalgebra/NumericalRecipiesInC/c5-7.pdf

Comment: That link is very good. It is about balancing round-off error with truncation error. But it also contradicts what you present. It claims that `h = x sqrt(eps)` is optimal for the 1-sided derivative, and suggests `h = x cbrt(eps)` is optimal for the central difference (5.7.8)

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: I knew you were going to raise that. From practice, the square root is better. But the true point is that `h` must be proportional to `x`. Constant and proportional to `√x` are nonsense.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: My point was that the same `h` is required for the same accuracy and that by increasing `h` you will get round the machine precision problem but at a cost of accuracy.

Comment: @Troubadour: I can't agree with you. The floating-point representation of numbers ensures a given relative accuracy, and all error calculus is based on relative errors. In this context, thinking in terms of absolute errors is counter-productive and leads to gross mistakes.

Comment: @YvesDaoust How does the choice of `h` change for the second derivative?

Comment: @random9: use the cube root of epsilon.

Comment: why square root?

Comment: @piotr: because it is midway.

Comment: @YvesDaoust wouldn't eps/2 be midway? Also since epsilon is  1ulp, can you get an increment of less than eps on a floating point number?

Comment: @piotr: no and this is why ε/2 is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider the precision needed.

At first glance, since `|y| = 5.49756e14` and `epsi = 1e-4`, you need at least `⌈log2(5.49756e14)-log2(1e-4)⌉ = 63` bits of significand precision (that is the number of bits used to encode the digits of your number, also known as mantissa) for `y` and `y+epsi` to be considered different.

The double-precision floating-point format only has 53 bits of significand precision (assuming it is 8 bytes). So, currently, `f1`, `f2` and `f3` are exactly the same because `y`, `y+epsi` and `y-epsi` are equal.

Now, let's consider the limit : `y = 1e20`, and the result of your function, `10x^3 + y^3`. Let's ignore `x` for now, so let's take `f = y^3`. Now we can calculate the precision needed for `f(y)` and `f(y+epsi)` to be different : `f(y) = 1e60` and `f(epsi) = 1e-12`. This gives a minimum significand precision of `⌈log2(1e60)-log2(1e-12)⌉ = 240` bits.

Even if you were to use the `long double` type, assuming it is 16 bytes, your results would not differ : `f1`, `f2` and `f3` would still be equal, even though `y` and `y+epsi` would not.

If we take `x` into account, the maximum value of `f` would be `11e60` (with `x = y = 1e20`). So the upper limit on precision is `⌈log2(11e60)-log2(1e-12)⌉ = 243` bits, or at least 31 bytes.

One way to solve your problem is to use another type, maybe a bignum used as fixed-point.

Another way is to rethink your problem and deal with it differently. Ultimately, what you want is `f1 - f2`. You can try to decompose `f(y+epsi)`. Again, if you ignore `x`, `f(y+epsi) = (y+epsi)^3 = y^3 + 3*y^2*epsi + 3*y*epsi^2 + epsi^3`. So `f(y+epsi) - f(y) = 3*y^2*epsi + 3*y*epsi^2 + epsi^3`.

Answer (score 0):

The *only* way to calculate gradient is calculus.

Gradient is a vector:

```
g(x, y) = Df/Dx i + Df/Dy j
```

where (i, j) are unit vectors in x and y directions, respectively.

One way to approximate derivatives is first order differences:

```
Df/Dx ~ (f(x2, y)-f(x1, y))/(x2-x1)
```

and

```
Df/Dy ~ (f(x, y2)-f(x, y1))/(y2-y1)
```

That doesn't look like what you're doing.

You have a closed form expression:

```
g(x, y) = 30*x^2 i + 3*y^2 j
```

You can plug in values for (x, y) and calculate the gradient exactly at any point.  Compare that to your differences and see how well your approximation is doing.

How you implement it numerically is your responsibility.   (10^19)^3 = 10^57, right?

What is the size of double on your machine?  Is it a 64 bit IEEE double precision floating point number?

Comment: Actually I use 10*x^3 +y^3 just as a testbench. The real problem I want my algorithm to solve does not have analytical expression, it is actually a black box function.

Comment: Yes, but you asked how to calculate the gradient.  You did a smart thing: You have an analytical solution you can compare to the numerical scheme you come up with.  I knew what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
dx = (1+abs(x))*eps,   dfdx = (f(x+dx,y) - f(x,y)) / dx
dy = (1+abs(y))*eps,   dfdy = (f(x,y+dy) - f(x,y)) / dy
```

to get meaningful step sizes for large arguments.

Use `eps = 1e-8` for one-sided difference formulas, `eps = 1e-5` for central difference quotients.

Explore automatic differentiation (see autodiff.org) for derivatives without difference quotients and thus much smaller numerical errors.

Comment: -1: Just because x is large does not mean that you can take a larger h! Evaluating the gradient of f(x) at x=1 is the same problem as evaluating the gradient of g(x) = f(x-1000) at x = 1001 i.e. the same h is required.

Comment: @Troubadour: No, actually not. At `x=1e10` an `eps=1e-8` will give exactly no difference between `x` and `x+eps` in `double`. This is exactly the same situation as in the question. Of course close to roots of a function you will always get cancellation errors that are disproportionate to the function value, but this does not invalidate that you get the (relative) best results if you toggle bit 26 (onesided) or bit 17 (symmetric) of the mantissa -- or perform arithmetic operations with a similar effect.

Comment: In your example, evaluation of `f(x)` around `x=1` has an optimistic evaluation error bound of `|f'(1)|·mu`, while already the evaluation of `x-1000` close to `x=1001` will incur a floating point error of up to `1000·mu`, so that a lowball for the evaluation error bound of `f(x-1000)` is `|f'(1)|·1000·mu`, i.e., an appreciably larger error.

Answer (score 0):

We can examine the behaviour of the error in the derivative using the following program - it calculates the 1-sided derivative and the central difference based derivative using a varying step size. Here I'm using x and y ~ 10^10, which is smaller than what you were using, but should illustrate the same point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
double f(double x, double y) {
    return 10 * pow(x, 3) + pow(y, 3);
}

double f_x(double x, double y) {
    return 3 * 10 * pow(x,2);
}

double f_y(double x, double y) {
    return 3 * pow(y,2);
}

int main()
{
    // double x = -5897182590.8347721;
    // double y = 269857217.0017581;
    double x = 1.13041e+10;
    double y = -5.49756e+10;
    //double x = 10.1;
    //double y = -5.2;

    double epsi = 1e8;
    for(int i=0; i<60; ++i) {
    double dfx_n = (f(x+epsi,y) - f(x,y))/epsi;
    double dfx_cd = (f(x+epsi,y) - f(x-epsi,y))/(2*epsi);
    double dfx = f_x(x,y);
    cout<<epsi<<" "<<fabs(dfx-dfx_n)<<" "<<fabs(dfx - dfx_cd)<<std::endl;
    epsi/=1.5;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output shows that a 1-sided difference gets us an optimal error of about `1.37034e+13` at a step length of about 100.0. Note that while this error looks large, as a relative error it is 3.5746632302764072e-09 (since the exact value is `3.833e+21`)

In comparison the 2-sided difference gets an optimal error of about `1.89493e+10` with a step size of about `45109.3`. This is three-orders of magnitude better, (with a much larger step-size).

How can we work out the step size? The link in the comments of Yves Daosts answer gives us a ballpark value:

`h=x_c sqrt(eps)` for 1-Sided, and `h=x_c cbrt(eps)` for 2-Sided.

But either way, if the required step size for decent accuracy at x ~ 10^10 is 100.0, the required step size with x ~ 10^20 is going to be 10^10 larger too. So the problem is simply that your step size is **way** too small.

This can be verified by increasing the starting step-size in the above code and resetting the x/y values to the original values.

Then expected derivative is `O(1e39)`, best 1-sided error of about `O(1e31)` occurs near a step length of `5.9e10`, best 2-sided error of about `O(1e29)` occurs near a step length of `6.1e13`.

Comment: I've no idea how that happened.. Should have been an edit , but somehow became a new post. Axed the older one.

Answer (score 0):

As numerical differentiation is ill conditioned (which means a small error could alter your result significantly) you should consider to use [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula). This way you can calculate the n-th derivative with an integral. This will lead to less problems with considering accuracy and stability.

Comment: This could be a really useful answer.  But for it to be a spectacular answer, you'd want to have some sample code here showing how you would use the formula in this case (even if you didn't go all the way and implement the numerical integration).